# Drawing a simple graph using projected lines

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, charts, highcharts

I need to draw a rather simple graph for a web project.

The data will always be the same, so the graph line will not change. However, I need to draw on top of the graph 2 projected lines, highlighting some aspect of the graph. These lines will change depending on some variable.
Here is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: chart]

I looked at Chart.js, Chartist and a few other libraries but did not see any examples that will draw those projected lines that I need.

Can someone please point me to a library which can accomplish this?

Comment: look into nvd3 examples http://nvd3.org/examples/

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it with highcharts.

I have found some almost exactly suiting example and slightly modified it:
http://jsfiddle.net/mt2becws/1/

Below there are calls setting "crosshair" after some time:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    addCrosshair(3,14.5);
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function() {
    addCrosshair(2,5.7);
}, 2000);
```

And the part of the code really doing it is:

```
function addCrosshair(x,y) {
chart.xAxis[0].addPlotLine({
    id: 'xPlotLine'+x,
    value: x,
    width: 1,
    color: '#C0C0C0'
});

chart.yAxis[0].addPlotLine({
    id: 'yPlotLine'+y,
    value: y,
    width: 1,
    color: '#C0C0C0'
});
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, but I spent the day doing this in D3 and it seems to be working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to do this using D3, by following this example here [My Favorite tooltip method for a line graph](http://www.d3noob.org/2014/07/my-favourite-tooltip-method-for-line.html)

Had to modify a few things, like the positioning of the tooltips (also using divs for this so I can also style them) and stop the projected x line where it meets the graph path, amongst other things.

But here is a snapshot of the result:

[image]